# View similar to Google Photos

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I am trying to make a Layout similar to Google's Photos app. As far as I could understand I think its a Gridview with headers. But I don't think it ends there. I have already seen [Tonic Artos solution](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders). Can someone give suggestions / thoughts on this?  [image: Photos Screen shot]